# How to increase FPS? (UPBGE)

Tags: modeling, game-engine, performance, logic-bricks

I'm nearing the completion of my game, but I've noticed that average FPS on my gaming PC is 30FPS, which makes me think that on regular PCs it will be unplayable.

1)Any general ideas on how to increase FPS? I have decimated objects with 600k vertices down to 3k yet I haven't noticed much FPS change.
2)I noticed that there is a 20% FPS change between looking towards a building with many objects (30FPS) and looking away from it (36FPS). Is there a way to keep FPS consistent?

I appreciate any help. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are using upbge 0.3. Do you have a skeleton in your scene? If your answer is yes, all I can say is: Upgrade to upbge 0.2.5. Because upbge 0.3 is a very weak engine for skeletons. Maybe it will be fixed with updates. If not, you can use the user's scripts on this youtube link (https://www.youtube.com/c/JacobMerrill/videos). Optimization is better if upbge is at 0.2.5. If your map is too large, go to the scene's main camera and enable this setting.[image]